# How do I insert a huge data strings to a URL link individually in Python

Tags: python

Suppose I am having a collection of random strings in a .txt file and the data in it can be showcased as follows:

```
a4HpekGN78MaHcT0vcGA
R1gnLzvsvgvf2hU08jqO
CsWCv0s6OZGEgAXAuhgZ
1293gdxhIUpIbTQbBqJc
vbCAyd6IbVfIjgkzJXJt
```

and I want to add this value individually to a URL

e.g. https://example.com/?stringvalue=**a4HpekGN78MaHcT0vcGA**/action?complete

I am a beginner at Python and want to develop my skills by working on individual projects.

Comment: Do you also want to run a request on the URL? Adding URL parameters is a piece of cake if you use a module like `requests`: https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls

Answer (score 0):

This will be a use of python's f-string. I do not know what you are going to do with the url, but to update it, you can use the following code.

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        url = f"https://example.com/?stringvalue=**{line.strip()}**/action?complete"
        print(url) # or whatever you want
```